# Webpack error: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Tags: javascript, webpack, three.js, babeljs

I got this message from webpack:

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

in my gulpfile:

```
// js task
const js = () => {
  return src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: [['@babel/env']],
      plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }]]
    }))
    .pipe(webpack({
      mode: 'development',
      devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    }))
    .pipe(mode.development( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }) ))
    .pipe(rename('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(mode.production( terser({ output: { comments: false }}) ))
    .pipe(mode.development( sourcemaps.write() ))
    .pipe(dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(mode.development( browserSync.stream() ));
}
```

i switched functions from:

```
init(){}
```

to:

```
 init = () => {
```

And then i get those errors, somebody can help?

Thanks already!

Edit:

I came up with the error in webpack so i changed all the functions to:

Well i removed all the  = () => from the functions but then i got some reference errors i guess:

```
class Experience {
    constructor(
      options = {
        containerSelector: "[data-app-container]"
      }
    ) {
      this.options = options;
      this.container = document.querySelector(this.options.containerSelector);
  
      // GSAP Plugins
      gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollSmoother);
  
      // Time
      this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
      this.time = 0;
  
      // THREE items
      this.renderer;
      this.camera;
      this.scene;
      this.controls;
      this.meshes = [];
  
      // Rotation
      this.targetRotation = 0;
  
      // Settings
      this.settings = {
        cameraDistance: 5,
        scalePeriod: 8
      };
  
      this.init();
    }
  
    init ()  {   
      this.createApp();
      this.createItems();
      this.initScroll();
      this.update();      
  
      this.container.classList.add("is-ready");
    };
  
    initScroll  ()  {
      this.scrollSmoother = ScrollSmoother.create({
        content: "#content",
        smooth: 1
      });
  
      // Add scroll triggers for each span item
      document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((span) => {
        ScrollTrigger.create({
          trigger: span,
          start: "top 90%",
          end: "bottom 10%",
          onUpdate: (self) => {
            const dist = Math.abs(self.progress - 0.5);
            const lightness = this.mapToRange(dist, 0, 0.5, 80, 100);
            span.style.setProperty("--l", lightness + "%");
          }
        });
      });
    };

  
    createApp () {
      // Renderer
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: false,
        alpha: true
      });
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(1.5);
      this.renderer.setSize(
        this.container.offsetWidth,
        this.container.offsetHeight
      );
      this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  
      // Camera
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45,
        this.container.offsetWidth / this.container.offsetHeight,
        1,
        10000
      );

      this.camera.position.set(0, 0, this.settings.cameraDistance);
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();   

      // Orbit Controls
      this.controls = new OrbitControls(
        this.camera,
        this.renderer.domElement
      );
      
      this.controls.enableKeys = false;
      this.controls.enableZoom = false;
      this.controls.enableDamping = false;
  
      // Resize the renderer on window resize
      window.addEventListener(
        "resize",
        () => {
          this.camera.aspect =
            this.container.offsetWidth / this.container.offsetHeight;
          this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          this.renderer.setSize(
            this.container.offsetWidth,
            this.container.offsetHeight
          );
        },
        true
      );
  
      // Ambient Light
      let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
      this.scene.add(ambientLight);
  
      // Directional Light
      let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
      directionalLight.position.set(5, 3, 2);
      directionalLight.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      this.scene.add(directionalLight);
    };
  
    createItems ()  {
      // Box
      let boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
      let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
      });
  
      const itemCount = 40;
      for (let i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, material);
        mesh.position.y = 13 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
        mesh.position.x = 3 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
        mesh.position.z = 4 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * Math.random();
        mesh.rotationSpeed = Math.random() * 0.01 + 0.005;
        this.scene.add(mesh);
        this.meshes.push(mesh);
      }
    };
  
    updateItems ()  {
      const time = this.time;
      const amplitude = 0.05;
      const period = this.settings.scalePeriod;
  
      const baseScale = 0.2;
      const scaleEffect =
        baseScale + amplitude * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * (time / period));
  
      this.meshes.forEach((mesh) => {
        mesh.scale.set(scaleEffect, scaleEffect, scaleEffect);
  
        // Update rotation
        mesh.rotation.x += mesh.rotationSpeed;
      });
  
      // Update camera
      const cameraRange = 10;
      this.camera.position.y = this.mapToRange(
        this.scrollSmoother.progress,
        0,
        1,
        cameraRange,
        -cameraRange
      );
    };
  
    mapToRange (value, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax){
      return ((value - inMin) * (outMax - outMin)) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
    };
  
    update () { 

      this.time = this.clock.getElapsedTime();
      this.updateItems();     
  
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);     
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update);

      console.log(this.clock.getElapsedTime())
    };
  }
  
new Experience();
```

But then i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clock')
    at update (gsap-three.js:188:1)
```

Comment: there's a difference in functionality between `function myFunc` and `const myFunc = () =>`. Scopes (`this`) etc. Revert this file and you should be good.

Comment: I thinks the scope isn't good after changing the functions to normal?